# Apache Server: Editing httpd.conf file (permission denied)

Tags: apache, logging, permissions, config

So I just recently downloaded Apache server with all of its files (httpd, apr, apr-util, pcre) following the instructions dictated here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html

However, after set-up, when I tried to start my Apache server, which is located in my usr/local/bin/, I was prompted with this message:

```
[allen@allen-lnx ~]$ /usr/local/bin/apachectl start
(13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /usr/local/logs/error_log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

After some research, I have found that I need to edit my httpd.conf file, which I did so earlier to allow for the correct ServerName and Listen options.  However, I am unsure as to how to edit my conf file to allow for access to the "logs" directory.

Notably, the command will run when I use the "sudo" command, but I would prefer to not always use that since it seems like a work around.

Any help would appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:** I've actually noticed that I may have two httpd.conf files, which is proving to be a little troublesome.  The other one is located in my root /etc/ directory (etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf).  I think my modified question now is... which one should I be keeping?  Is the /etc/ version the one that is built in, as indicated by faff's comment below?

**Current Solution:** I figured I would just accept the fact that I need to use sudo when editing this file since I need to be root.  I might change it later so that I'm always running as root, but for now, `sudo` will suffice.

Comment: Which Linux distribution is this? It's usually much easier to install apache via the package manager for your OS. It'll keep you updated on security patches, and it will be properly integrated with the rest of the system to ensure it's configured correctly for your setup.

Comment: I'm running Oracle Linux 6.4.  Does that help?

Comment: Why can't you use the apache that Oracle Linux ships? Looking at http://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL6/4/base/x86_64/ it seems there are builds of Apache HTTPD 2.2.15 available in  httpd-2.2.15-26.0.1.el6.x86_64.rpm etc.

Comment: I used the "sudo yum install httpd" command, and it says everything is up to date.  :X

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like an issue with he filesystem permissions. Make sure the `/usr/local/logs/` directory exists and is writeable by the user you're running Apache as.

If you don't want to have your `logs` directory writeable by normal user, you can create the log file:

```
sudo touch /usr/local/logs/error_log
```

And then change the owner of the file to the correct user:

```
sudo chown allen /usr/local/logs/error_log
```

Assuming you want to run Apache as the user `allen`.

If you want to change the location of Apache logfile, look for the `ErrorLog` directive in your httpd.conf file (you will have to add it if it's not there):

```
ErrorLog path/to/logfile
```

Comment: Is there no way to go about doing this within the httpd.conf file?  Or does it have to be a more "manual" means?  Because I feel like if I ever make new files, I might need to change the permissions again, whereas fixing the configuration file will solve this directly.  Unless I am mistaken...

Comment: Also, when I tried the above, it runs without errors, but I checked and it's not actually starting the server.  I know this because when I try to stop it, it says "httpd (no pid file) not running".  Calling "sudo" is my solution to all of this, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something...

Comment: @Zhouster - when you started the server, was there anything written to the logfile? By looking at it you should see what exactly went wrong. Also, I added instructions for changing default logile location to my answer.

Comment: There is actually a lot in my error_log.  It says "could not create /usr/local/logs/httpd.pid" and "could not log pid to file /usr/local/logs/httpd.pid".  When I run sudo for my operations, I'm able to start the server and visit my home website, but when I run the status command, it says it cannot find the requested URL.  I'm wondering if I'm missing something.  I'm running apachectl.  Should I be running something else?

Comment: It seems like there's still a problem with file permissions. You can try to create the `/usr/local/logs/httpd.pid` file manually, or change its location with the `PidFile` directive in your httpd.conf.

Comment: I have changed the location for the PidFile directive, but right now, the index.html file in my htdcos is not showing up when I try to look at the ip address I am listening to.  So, I have the ServerName set to 127.0.0.1:8000, and Listen to that same value.  Any potential errors?

Comment: Thank you Essenti.  I added in your ErrorLog suggestion, and your other comments have helped me gain a better understanding of Apache.  :)

Answer (score 3):

For everyone that is using SELinux, if you deleted the folder or come across similar problems you may need to do several things.

Re-link the folder with `ln -s /var/log/httpd /etc/httpd/logs`
By default logs are kept under the var folder but are referenced in the /etc/httpd/logs folder

Apply SELinux security permissions with `chcon system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 /etc/httpd/logs`

And of course run everything as admin

Comment: Thanks! My permission was correct but it did not work. I spent more than an hour before I read your answer, finding solutions. This (SELinux) was exactly my problem. That **chcon** did not work for me. So I did, **set enforce 0**.

Comment: Would like to confirm that SELinux was preventing my `httpd` server from running on Fedora 22. This is still a current solution for systems using SELinux.

Answer (score 0):

Changing SELinux security policy to **permissive** fixed my problem.

Before fix my SELinux worked with enforced mode:

```
$ sestatus -v
sestatus -v
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      30
```

I changed security policy in SELinux configuration file and in the system.

```
#/etc/selinux/config
SELINUX=permissive

# In terminal set SELinux to run in permissive mode.
$ setenforce 0
```

After fix my SELinux worked with enforced mode:

```
$ sestatus -v
SELinux status:                 enabled
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          permissive
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      30
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are stuck with the SElinux policies, I was able to do it by creating a custom policy

Basically I wanted to move the `/var/log/httpd` to my own directory under `/r/`

So I run the following

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/r/www(/.*)?"
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_log_t "/r/logs(/.*)?"

restorecon -Rv /z/logs/
restorecon -Rv /z/www/

service httpd restart
# worked
```